# Cron expression to skip only public holidays of the year

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cron

I've a ASP.Net MVC application, We are using calender control to pick the date on UI. We are using cron expression to set the public holiday date. My requirement is Date picker on UI should not allow user to select public holidays date that are set using cron expression. I would like to verify if my cron expression is correct or not. If its correct what's the problem with my C# code. My function is not returning valid dates. Its returning holidays also as a part of valid dates.

Following are the list of holidays I need to skip - New Year, Memorial Day, Independence Day, Labor Day, Thanksgiving, Day after thanksgiving,Chrismas Evening, Chrismas.

Appreciate your help ! Below the code and cron expression, At the end of GetDate function I'm trying to get valid date.
I'm looking for cron expression of just public holidays (Not Weekends, Not vacations).

```
List<DateTime> GetDates(DateTime cutOffDate, bool isAlways = false, string Code = null, string TestMethod = null)
        {
            var validDates = new List<DateTime>();
            try
            {
                List<string> cronExpressionStrings = new List<string>();
                cronExpressionStrings.Add("0 0 0 1 1 ? *"); // New Year Day
                cronExpressionStrings.Add("0 0 0 ? 5 MON#4 *"); //Memorial Day
                cronExpressionStrings.Add("0 0 0 4 7 ? *"); //Independence Day
                cronExpressionStrings.Add("0 0 0 ? 9 MON#1"); //Labor Day
                cronExpressionStrings.Add("0 0 0 ? 11 THU#4 *");//Thanksgiving
                cronExpressionStrings.Add("0 0 0 ? 11 FRI#4 *");//Day after Thanksgiving
                cronExpressionStrings.Add("0 0 0 24 12 ? *"); //Chrismas Evening
                cronExpressionStrings.Add("0 0 0 25 12 ? *"); //Chrismas

                var currentDateTimeWithPaddingDays = AddPaddingDaysToDate(DateTime.UtcNow);

                if (cronExpressionStrings?.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (string cronExpressionString in cronExpressionStrings)
                    {
                        var cronExpression = new CronExpression(cronExpressionString);

                        //If the first padded date is the same as the first Cron date then add that day to valid days
                        var firstCronDate = cronExpression.GetNextValidTimeAfter(DateTime.UtcNow);
                        if (firstCronDate.Value.Date == currentDateTimeWithPaddingDays.Date)
                        {
                            if (!validDates.Contains(currentDateTimeWithPaddingDays.Date))
                            {
                                validDates.Add(currentDateTimeWithPaddingDays.ToUniversalTime().Date);
                            }
                        }

                        DateTimeOffset? currentDateTimeWithPaddingDaysOffset = currentDateTimeWithPaddingDays;

                        //If no drop down padding days were used, then get next Cron date
                        if (currentDateTimeWithPaddingDays.Date == DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
                        {
                            currentDateTimeWithPaddingDaysOffset = cronExpression.GetNextValidTimeAfter(currentDateTimeWithPaddingDays).Value;
                        }

                        for (var dateTimeOffset = currentDateTimeWithPaddingDaysOffset;
                             (dateTimeOffset?.Date < cutOffDate.Date);)
                        {
                            if (!validDates.Contains(dateTimeOffset.Value.Date))
                            {
                                validDates.Add(dateTimeOffset.Value.Date);
                            }

                            dateTimeOffset = cronExpression.GetNextValidTimeAfter(dateTimeOffset.Value).Value;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var dateOnly = new DateTime(currentDateTimeWithPaddingDays.Year, currentDateTimeWithPaddingDays.Month, currentDateTimeWithPaddingDays.Day);

                    validDates.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + cutOffDate.Subtract(dateOnly).Days)
                                                  .Select(offset => dateOnly.AddDays(offset))
                                                  .ToArray());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("test", ex);
                throw;
            }

            return validDates.OrderBy(d => d).ToList();
        }


private DateTime AddPaddingDaysToDate(DateTime date)
        {
            try
            {
                var groupName = DropDownGroupName.PaddingMatrix.ToString();
                var paddingMatrix = (from b in context.DropDownValue.AsNoTracking()
                                     join d in context.DropDownGroup.AsNoTracking() on b.TableCode equals d.ID
                                     where d.TableName == groupName
                                     select new DropDownValueArgs
                                     {
                                         ID = d.ID,
                                         Name = b.Name,
                                         Value = b.Value,
                                         Description = b.Description,
                                         RegionCode = b.RegionCode
                                     }).ToList();
                if (paddingMatrix.Count > 0)
                {
                    var paddingdays = paddingMatrix.Where(z => string.Equals(z.Name, date.Hour.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && string.Equals(z.RegionCode, date.DayOfWeek.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Select(z => z.Value).FirstOrDefault();
                    date = date.AddDays(double.Parse(paddingdays, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("AddPaddingDaysToDate()", ex);
                throw;
            }

            return date;
        }
```

Comment: I think we will at least need to see this "crone" expression before anything else can happen.

Comment: @robbpriestley - Thank you for your response. We are trying below cron expressions, These are defined in the database. 0 0 0 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
0 0 12 1 1 ? *
0 0 12 ? 5 MON#4 *
0 0 12 4 7 ? *

Comment: It's "cron" by the way, not "crone". Edit your question, and add the cron statement(s) into the question using a code block. Pasting the code into the comments makes it difficult to read. Also post the section of ASP.NET MVC code that is using cron.

Comment: @robbpriestley Thank you for your response, Corrected my typo, Also posted C# code.

Comment: Please fix your formatting. The format of your question is bad, and you are going to get downvoted. Put the cron statement(s) into a code block. Put the `public List GetDates(` bit into a code block. Etc

Comment: @robbpriestley - Corrected the format. Appreciate your response.

Comment: OK, that's looking much better! Now, please edit your question and explain which "holidays" you are referring to. Weekends? Civic holidays? Vacations?

Comment: @robbpriestley Thank you for your response, I've added list of holidays. I've also updated description of question which will help to understand my goal. Thank you again !

Comment: OK, looking much, much better. I will look into this as soon as I can. In the meantime, I'll upvote your question and maybe someone else will help you answer it.

Comment: @robbpriestley Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want any of the valid days to be the holidays defined in your cron expressions, but in your code you say:

```
if (firstCronDate.Value.Date == currentDateTimeWithPaddingDays.Date)
{
    if (!validDates.Contains(currentDateTimeWithPaddingDays.Date))
    {
        validDates.Add(currentDateTimeWithPaddingDays.ToUniversalTime().Date);
    }
}
```

Which is basically like saying "if the date is a holiday, add it to the list of valid dates" which is the complete opposite of what you want, isn't it?

So maybe instead say:

```
if (firstCronDate.Value.Date != currentDateTimeWithPaddingDays.Date)
```

If you are having trouble with your cron expressions, you can test them here: https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html